# Как запретить обработку eslint атрибута?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint

как запретить eslint правку атрибута maxWidth на max-width
нужно так

```
<modal
      name="category-modal"
      transition="pop-out"
      height="auto"
      width="95%"
      :scrollable="true"
      maxWidth="960"
    >
```

а он преобразовывает вот так

```
<modal
      name="category-modal"
      transition="pop-out"
      height="auto"
      width="95%"
      :scrollable="true"
      max-width="960"
    >
```

Comment: Возможно,  это Vetur делает. Посмотрите там в настройках

Comment: ничего такого нет

Comment: https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятна ваша причина изменения `eslint`'а, ведь он правильно обрабатывает форматирование, в `html` атрибутах допускается написание только `kebab-case` варианта, то есть `max-width`, но никак не `maxWidth`. В пропсах же наоборот, вы получаете переменную в виде `camelCase`.

В самой документации об этом написано: [Prop Casing (camelCase vs kebab-case)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: {
        maxWidth: Number
    },
    template: '<p>Max width: <b>{{ maxWidth }}</b></p>'
});

new Vue({ el: "#app" });
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <my-component :max-width="10" />
    <my-component :maxWidth="20" />
    <my-component :maxwidth="30" />
</div>
```

Comment: да был косяк в документации модуля, теперь все ок, спасибо всем